# Как сделать обновление в базе данных циклом foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Пожалуйста дайте подскажку как обновить базу при помощи форыча. Вчера получилось, а щас нифига не получается, записывается во все строки только последняя строка.

Скрипт регулярным выражением форматирует по шаблону телефоны и должен перезаписывать на правильный формат. Но елки палки, цикл записывает в базу один и тот же номер, гори он в аду

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
  define('DB_HOST', '111');
  define('DB_USER', '111');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '111');
  define('DB_NAME', '111');
$dbc= mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('error DB');
$query="SELECT * FROM user";
mysqli_query($dbc, 'set names utf8');
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or ('ошибка ');

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $user_id=$row['user_id'];
    $string=$row['telefon']; 
    $pattern = [
    '~(?:[^\d\s]+|(?<=\d)\s(?=\d))~',
    '~(?<=\b)(?=\d)~',
    '~\b[8](\d+\b)~'
];
$replace = ['', '+', '37$1'];
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
$masiv[]=$string;  
   }
   foreach($masiv as &$telefon)
{
    $query="UPDATE user SET telefon='$telefon'";
    $data=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('error');

}

?>
```

Comment: Запатронен?) Я просто свои шаблоны узнал в вашем коде )

Comment: При UPDATE нужно использовать WHERE ( "UPDATE user SET telefon='$telefon' WHERE ...", а так Вы ему сами говорите во все строки колонки user записать "телефон"

Comment: я самый))))) вы везде что ли я прописываю WHERE но этот WHERE берет только последний айдишник в базе

Comment: @Павел Буланов а почему код старый? Я же вчера вам для замены 80 на 375 переписывал шаблон.

Comment: @Павел Буланов ну это смотря на какой ресурс смотреть )) Тут я так же, как и на пхп.су бываю ежедневно :)

Comment: про замену помню и учитываю его, но пока постигаю чтобы хоть как -то менялось как нужно

Comment: @Павел Буланов на самом деле, ваш код надо полностью переписать. Я не за ПК сейчас, поэтому пока помочь не могу, но здесь множество знающих людей, вам нужно только корректно задать вопрос.

Comment: вам и так спасибо за регулярку, вчера даже как-то произошло что все нормально записалось, но решил попробовать еще раз чтобы понять и все рухнуло от чего капец бешусь уже бы сдал работу и приступил бы за другую. тогда буду переписывать хороших выходных!

Answer (score 0):

```
$telefon='';
$user_id=...;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "UPDATE user SET telefon=? WHERE user_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $telefon, $user_id);
foreach($masiv as $telefon)
{
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Только вот у вас каждый раз будут обновляться все телефоны в таблице с таким SQL. Может там куда `WHERE` вставить (потелепатировал слегка)?

Comment: вест код до форыча нужно поместить в цикл WHILE?

Comment: @ПавелБуланов я вам привел пример, как правильно делать много однотипных запросов. Так как у вас в принципе неправильный SQL-запрос, обновляющий все записи в таблице, я не знаю, какой логикой вы собирались руководствоваться и, поэтому, более конкретно объяснить не смогу

Comment: буду разбираться, для начала ищучу функции новые для меня в вашем коде